# How to replace the value with NAs with a condition

Tags: r, loops, replace, na, outliers

I am trying to use the Chauvenet criterion to remove outliers in R. Chauvenet criteria helps with detecting outliers with a probability band based on the mean and SD. Some information about Chauvenets and the source of the code that im using:
https://influentialpoints.com/Training/chauvenets_outlier-id-criterion.htm
https://github.com/tillrohrmann/edu-polytechnique-map553/blob/master/map553/Chauvenet.R

I have a large dataset around 100000 data. Im hoping the code will return all the values above >0.5 i.e the data without outliers.

I am new to R. To easen the data cleaning process I want to use this code (but as <0.5) to replace all the values that do not fulfil this criterion with **a NA** in the same dataframe or a new dataframe so that I can verify the outliers myself before removing them. This is my code `

```
      Chauvenet <- function(datapoints, loop=TRUE){
      numdatapoints <- nrow(data)
#calculating normalised distance from the mean
      dist <- abs(data - colMeans(data))/sapply(data,sd)
#calculating the probability to see such point assuming the distribution in normal 
      prob <- apply(dist,c(1,2),function(x) numdatapoints*dnorm(x))
#Selecting the points that have only a probablity >0.5
      sel <-  (apply(prob,c(1,2),function(x) x<=0.5))
      idx <- rowSums(sel) == ncol(data)
      datapoints <- data[idx,]
      if(loop == TRUE){
        mutate(replace(newdata,NA)
          numdatapoints <- nrow(data)
          dist <- abs(data - colMeans(data))/sapply(data,sd)
          prob <- apply(dist,c(1,2),function(x) numdatapoints*dnorm(x))
          sel <-  apply(prob,c(1,2),function(x) x<=0.5)
          idx <- rowSums(sel) == ncol(data)
          datapoints <- data[idx,]
        }
        
    
      return(datapoints)
    }
```

`
It would be nice to get some help on how to modify the code better.

Comment: Can you refine your question a little?  It's difficult to understand what your code does.  What does the `Chauvenet` function return and how is this different from what you ultimately want?   Can you add a small reproducible example?

Comment: Hi George. I have modified my question a bit. Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: It's still difficult to understand. You have changed the code from the github version such that I don't see how it can work now.  (eg calling the`datapoints` frame `data` sometimes and removing the `while` loop).  But to give you some hints, it seems the `sel` matrix indicates which of your points are to be kept, so if you return this you can compare to it `datapoints` to see which are being removed.

Comment: Thank you. I have a dataset with birth related variables that I want to analyse. But even with this original code I am not getting an output. For one variable I got a single value and for another Im getting integer (0).

Comment: If you can add an example dataset it will be a lot easier to help